# TSQL Условия выборок

Tags: sql, sql-server

один тот же препод , который ведет первую дисциплину например за 200 ( подходит по условию выборки) и другую ( за 100 например и не подходит по условию выборки) чтобы оно не выводило этого преподавателя после выполнения запроса?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя, [Фамилия],[Имя],[Отчество],[Стоимость_часа]   
FROM Преподаватели2 inner  JOIN Нагрузка 
ON Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя=Нагрузка.Код_преподавателя
WHERE  Фамилия  LIKE '[А-К]%' and Стоимость_часа>=150;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Comment: `except` можно.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что правильно тебя понял. Но тебе видимо надо вывести всех преподователей у которых каждая `Стоимость_часа` больше,  чем заданное значение. Если так, то вот один из возможных вариантов:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя, [Фамилия],[Имя],[Отчество],[Стоимость_часа]   
FROM Преподаватели2 inner  JOIN Нагрузка 
ON Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя=Нагрузка.Код_преподавателя
WHERE Фамилия  LIKE '[А-К]%' and Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя not in 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя  
    FROM Преподаватели2 inner  JOIN Нагрузка 
    ON Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя=Нагрузка.Код_преподавателя
    WHERE   Стоимость_часа < 150
)
```

Или если `Стоимость_часа` находится в таблице `Нагрузка`, то еще проще:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя, [Фамилия],[Имя],[Отчество],[Стоимость_часа]   
FROM Преподаватели2 inner  JOIN Нагрузка 
  ON Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя=Нагрузка.Код_преподавателя
  WHERE Фамилия  LIKE '[А-К]%' and Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя not in 
  (
     SELECT DISTINCT Код_преподавателя  
     FROM Нагрузка 
     WHERE   Стоимость_часа < 150
  )
```